# Play Framework 2 Java Mock Plugin for Unit Testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am trying to write a Unit test for Play Framework 2.2. The class I am trying to test makes calls to a Play Plugin such as

```
Exception e = new Exception();
MongoLogger.error(e);
```

The class definition for the plugin is

```
MongoLogger extends Plugin
```

How can I use Mockito to Mock this class and register it. I want to avoid using FakeApplication for Unit tests. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the calls to `MongoLogger` to an interface, using wrapper design pattern:

```
public interface Logger {
    // methods
}

public interface DefaultLogger implements Logger {

    private final MongoLogger mongoLogger;

    public void error(Object e){
        monoLogger.error(e);
    }

}
```

In your production code use `Logger` interface wherever you call `MongoLogger`. In your test code, inject the mock instead:

```
Mockito.mock(Logger.class);
```

Comment: MongoLogger is not a field I can inject. It is a play plugin which is imported as `import plugins.MongoLogger;` and then its methods are called statically `MongoLogger.error(e)` I have no chance to inject the mocked object so I am not sure this would work

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the fakeApplication as objects are also persisted in the code I want to test. If anyone is interested it looks like this

```
Map<String, Object> additionalConfiguration = new HashMap<String, Object>();
List<String> additionalPlugins = Arrays.asList("plugins.MongoLogger");
running(Helpers.fakeApplication(additionalConfiguration, additionalPlugins), new Runnable() {
```

I get no NullPointerExceptions and I just clean up the object i insert after i am done with the test.